# gridview change text color base on value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, substring

I'm using onRowDataBound to change the text color of text as below but facing some issue..

```
protected void OnRowDataBound123(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TableCell statusCell1 = e.Row.Cells[1];
        if (statusCell1.Text != "-")
        {
            string[] a = statusCell1.Text.Split('/');
            if (a[0] != a[1])
            {
                statusCell1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I'm getting error in **Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.**
Thing i want to do here is compare the value before and after slash "/" if doesn't match to each other then the text color will become red,else black color.

Comment: Use statusCell1.Text.Split('/'). single quotes in split function

Comment: @Sami not working..

Comment: after  string[] a = statusCell1.Text.Split('/');   write condition i.e. if (a.Count > 1) {...} . Because may be there is no '/'  and array does not contain a[1].

Comment: i do the checking using this line : if (statusCell1.Text != "-")

Comment: I posted a solution. Hope that helps!

Comment: So the format should be like this **10/12** or gets red? Right!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to apply a String.Split on a TableCell

Try statusCell1.Text.Split('/')

(or something similar to .Text if that doesn't work.)

```
//Creating values for testing
//These are just for testing do not place this in your code
TableCell statusCell1 = new TableCell();
statusCell1.Text = "blah/blah blah";

//##################################
//These are the only lines you need
string[] splitString = statusCell1.Text.Split('/');
string resultingString = splitString[0];
string resultingString2 = splitString[1];
//##################################

//These are just for testing do not place this in your code
Console.WriteLine(resultingString);
Console.WriteLine(resultingString2);

//prints out: 
//blah 
//blah blah
```

Comment: statusCell1.Text = "blah/blah blah"; i need get from  e.Row.Cells[2];
your code not working..

Comment: You're not going to use statucCell.Text = "whatever." that was just a data sample. All you need are the three lines of code in the middle. I've marked the section of code for you in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Directly get value from row cell, try below, it is tested:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound123(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string cellValue = statusCell1 = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;
        if (cellValue != "-")
        {
            string[] a = cellValue.Split('/');
            if (a[0] != a[1])
            {
                e.Row.Cells[1].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: string cellValue = statusCell1 = e.Row.Cells[1].Text; error

Comment: Oops... Typo ... string cellValue = e.Row.Cells[1].Text;

Comment: statusCell1 doesnt exist in current content

Comment: Updated my answer to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            Label lblparent = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblRate");
            if (lblparent.Text != "-")
            {
                string[] a = lblparent.Text.Split('/');
                if (a[0] != a[1])
                {
                    lblparent.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    lblparent.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

this code solved my problem.

Comment: What was your expected output actually?

Comment: change text color if character before '/' and  after '/' is not match